# When progress completes, show POST result

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a progress bar in which i show progress when user inputs a value to form and submits the button.

On the basis on value, the query is run user input number of times and add records and then fetch them.

I added Ajax to show the result on the same page which is working fine but i want to print the content once the progress is complete.

I tried doing:

```
$(function(){
$("button").click(function(event){ 
    event.preventDefault();
    $.ajax({
        type:"POST",
        url:"result.php",
        data:$("#form").serialize(),
        success:function(data){
            var insert_records = $("#write_record").val();
            for(var i=0; i<insert_records; i++)
           $("progress").animate({ value: "+="+insert_records }, 5000);

          if($('progress').prop('value') == insert_records)
          {
                $("#content").html(data);

          } 
        }
    });
});
```

});

I have a doubt in my last part of code having If condition. I want to somehow get the value of value attribute of progress bar and compare it with the max value which is insert_records variable.

And then show the content using $("#content").html(data);

What is my mistake here?

Comment: Is progress the id of the progress bar? Are you using jqueryui progress bar?

Comment: I am using HTML5 progress bar and no its not the id

Answer (score 0):

The value of the progress bar takes 5000ms to update because of the animation, you need to get the value after it finishes by putting it inside the callback function:

```
$(function () {
    $("button").click(function () {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "result.php",
            data: $("#form").serialize(),
            success: function (data) {
                var insert_records = $("#write_record").val();
                var newValue = $('progress').prop('value') + insert_records;
                $("progress").animate({
                    value: "+=" + insert_records
                }, 1000, function () { // Animation complete.

                    if ($('progress').prop('value') == newValue) {
                        $("#content").html(data);
                    }
                });

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Note: I don't know about the for loop there maybe it's not necessary.

Comment: The code works fine if the value provided is 1 but it do not work for other values, 

Example: I entered 3 as input but after the increment in value attribute the value is set to 4. I have no idea why.

Comment: try removing the for loop

Comment: I tried removing the loop and the values are fine but when i tried doing 

var progress_attr = $('progress').prop('value');
                    console.log(progress_attr);

It is giving me 1 every time, even if the input is 4.

I am adding these lines after the if condition in the callback method

Comment: Thank you for your efforts but it did not help. Any ways thanks :)